# In C# why do I need to prefix MYClass when I name its namespace with MYClass also?

Tags: c#

I have created a class:

```
namespace MyClass {    

    public partial class MyClass: UserControl {
```

I want to use it in another project so I add the above project as reference and the instruction

```
using MyClass
```

but I still have to refer to the class as

```
MyClass.MyClass
```

and not just

```
MyClass
```

Why ?

Comment: It sounds like you did it correctly. Try posting a more complete sample.

Comment: Do you have another `MyClass` in there somewhere, causing an ambiguous reference?

Comment: Is there a level of ambiguity?.. IE you have an object named `MyClass` in multiple namespaces?

Comment: Is it an ambiguous class name, where you need to specify the namespace so the compiler knows which one you are talking about?

Comment: I forgot to say my namespace has the same name as my class. Still the context should be enough for compiler to distinguish.

Answer (score 5):

You may have other types with the same name in the current scope, so the compiler will require you to use the fully qualified name in order to distinguish the exact one you mean.

Comment: Is it because I use the same name for the namespace as the class ?

Comment: @user310291 - Yes. I suggest you read the following blog posts about why this is a bad practice (by Eric Lippert): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces/